# Can't see JMX entries in jconsole when using Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, jmx

we're evaluating switching over from the C3P0 connection pool to the Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool ([as described here](http://vigilbose.blogspot.com/2009/03/apache-commons-dbcp-and-tomcat-jdbc.html)).

It appears to work as a connection pool but I can't seem to see any JMX entries for it when I run jconsole.
Out of the box C3P0 gives lots of operations and attributes via JMX, the Tomcat 
JDBC Connection Pool gives none (for me).

According to the page linked above there is a jmxEnabled flag that defaults to true.  I've set this explicitly but it seems to make no difference.

What am I missing?

I'm running a fairly standard Java6/Spring/Hibernate app by the way.

Comment: are you using SpringSource tc Server? That article mentions that the "Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool" is only available in SpringSource's distribution of Tomcat (which makes the name of the connection pool a poor choice, IMO)

Comment: No we're not but our app runs fine with it on Tomcat 6, and another app has been using it for a few months on Tomcat 6 too.

Answer (score 12):

If you configure pool in your spring context, you should export bean manually. Autoexport works only if you confiugre pool in tomcat container and import it from JNDI. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#JMX

You may use this spring config for export pool information to JMX:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
   ... skipped ...
</bean>

<bean id="jmxExporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="beans">
        <map>
            <entry key="bean:name=DataSource" value="#{dataSource.getPool().getJmxPool()}"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Config works only in Spring version 3.0 and above, because it uses spring expression language

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped me.  For some reason, the pool wasn't initialized by using this technique directly, so I had to change it to
`<entry key="bean:name=DataSource" value="#{dataSource.createPool().getJmxPool()}"/>`
to get it to work

Comment: @JohnC probably a timing issue, you want `jmxExporter` to export after `dataSource` is initialized, not before; did you try this?  `<bean id="jmxExporter" depends-on="dataSource"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any entries under the tree

```
Catalina -> DataSource -> javax.sql.DataSource
```

This lists the number of active connections, idle connections, and a few other common stats.
Other then that, what kind of information are you hoping to get out of monitoring?

Comment: I don't have a DataSource entry under Catalina.

Comment: I also Don't see this entry. I am using Spring 3 with DBCP pool on Tomcat 5 using jdk 5

Answer (score 0):

Darren, if you don't see the object name under `Catalina/DataSource/javax.sql.DataSource/<name>` in JConsole, then I wonder if the datasource is defined incorrectly or perhaps it was not connected to the database when Tomcat was started.

Bruce

Comment: I am using spring and DBCP data source. I did not see catalina/DataSource in Jconsole. kindly give me Insights how to monitor pool size when using Spring 3 and DBCP connection pool.

Comment: Here is a Maven project that makes use of Spring 3 to expose a DBCP connection pool via JMX:

https://github.com/bsnyder/spring-jdbc-jmx

Note: There is a Thread.sleep in the App.select() method so that you can start up jconsole to peek at the JMX properties of the DataSource object.

Comment: Wao... You are great. Thanks allot. That's what I am looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

In support of Sean's post:

The placement of the `javax.sql.DataSource` entry in MBeans of JConsole is:

- `Catalina`

  - `DataSource`

    - `/[Name_of_deployed_application]` // e.g. "/DomainService

      - `/[Host_name_of_the_deployed_application]` //e.g. "localhost"

        - `javax.sql.DataSource`